# Filter a vector using a boolean array

Tags: rust

How do I use the `boolean_arr` to filter `ys` based on the `bool` values?

The arrays all have the same length.

```
fn main() {
    let xs: Vec<f32> = vec![300., 7.5, 10., 250.];
    let boolean_arr: Vec<bool> = xs.into_iter().map(|x| x > 10.).collect();

    let ys: Vec<f32> = vec![110.5, 50., 25., 770.];

    assert_eq!(wanted_vec, vec![110.5, 770.]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A different tack from Silvio's answer: a more efficient (but less generic) method would be to use [Vec::retain](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.retain) since it's guaranteed to traverse the subject in-order and you're guaranteeing that the subject and filter bitmap are the same size:

```rust
// don't even collect if not necessary, though that also applies to Silvio's suggestion
let mut bitmap = xs.into_iter().map(|x| x > 10.);

let mut ys: Vec<f32> = vec![110.5, 50., 25., 770.];
// could even use `unwrap_unchecked` if that's better codegen, but then that's UB if the bitmap length doesn't match the subject
ys.retain(|_| bitmap.next().unwrap());
let wanted_vec = ys;
```

Answer (score 7):

We can use [`zip`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/fn.zip.html) to combine the two and then filter the results. Here's a general-purpose function that works on arbitrary iterators.

```rust
fn filter_by<I1, I2>(bs: I1, ys: I2) -> impl Iterator<Item=<I2 as Iterator>::Item>
where I1: Iterator<Item=bool>,
      I2: Iterator {
  bs.zip(ys).filter(|x| x.0).map(|x| x.1)
}
```

And how to call it in your particular use case

```rust
let wanted_vec: Vec<_> = filter_by(boolean_arr.into_iter(), ys.into_iter()).collect();
```

Comment: I would return an iterator to avoid an explicit allocation (which is probably outside the scope of the question), but otherwise an excellent and succinct answer; take my upvote

Comment: Alternatively: `.filter_map(|(flag, val)| flag.then(|| val)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Silvio. Even though it is excellent and answers my question, I'm going to accept Masklinn's answer as it's better aligned with what I was looking for.